# Empty asp.net Resources Cache, provided by SQLResourceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, resourceproviderfactory

I've just implemented a `SQLResource` provider in my MVC2 application. When I change something in the database by hand or by a webform, I want the `ResourceProvider` to drop all it's resources and fetch them again from the database.

Does any one now how I can clear this `ResourceCache` that is managed by ASP.NET's own API?

Comment: When you implemented your resource provider, how did you handle caching of resources? Can we see some of your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

When you implementing SQLResourceProvider you should use caching together with database utility class. When creating cache you can define policy which contains ChangeMonitors property.I think adding SqlCacheDepency item to  ChangeMonitors property is what you looking for. Take a look a this classes [SqlCacheDepency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx)
 , [CacheItemPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx). I can provide code if you need it.